# MS edge graphical anomalies

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

On my website http://uus.diamedica.ee/et/tooted/veterinaaria/6 is having strange 1px graphical glitches in and around the red menu bar, that only occurs in MS edge. It's like small bits are bitten out of the menu ribbon, thus making it look uneven. I've tried changing fonts, backgrounds, margins, paddings, etc. And nothing seems to make it go away. I've tried different zoom levels, but still the same after refresh. 
Funny thing is, if you hover the menu items, then some of the bugs go away. Is anyone else having similar problems in MS edge and knows what´s causing it? Image below.

[image: issue]

additional screens

http://design.imago.ee/test/diamedica/screen1.png
http://design.imago.ee/test/diamedica/screen2.png

Comment: Any steps to reproduce. I checked on MS Edge (last version) looks fine for me. Without any artefacts. I use Win10 (1920x1080). Could you tell me which resolution do you have?

Comment: you still might be able to see it in here http://design.imago.ee/Diamedica/html/index4.html since it is a draft version, but i fixed the issue on live site.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow i was able to fix the problem (at least in the computer that it appeared in the first place) by giving .menu-ribbon position relative, z-index 2000 and bottom value -1px. The issue should be still available to see in the draft version for those who are interested, http://design.imago.ee/Diamedica/html/index3.html is the url, open it up and hit refresh once after you´ve first loaded the page. At least im still seeing it in the draft version.

Answer (score 0):

I also try to make a test by normally visiting the site in Edge.

Site looks correctly without any issue.

Below is my testing result.

[image]

Let us know, If there is anything that we are missing.

We will again try to make a test to reproduce the issue.

Are you working with low memory or with so much load on Edge?

Try to close all other site and open your site and check whether you can produce the issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, i got it fixed by that time actually. I set a position relative and a bottom value to -1px plus a z-index. Somehow that was able to make those odd graphical glitches go away.